# How can i pick the comma separated attribute value in xml one by one as loop in c#

Tags: c#, xml, entity-attribute-value

I would like to use comma separated attribute values defined under `TestCondition` in xml one by one in loop for further execution of my code.Please find the sample xml as follows:

```
    <DrWatson>
  <Bugs Name="Testing New things" TestCondition="STATE,STATUS">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>NeedsReview</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>ToFix</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
  <Bugs Name="STATUS" TestCondition="STATUS">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>NeedsReview</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>ToFix</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
</DrWatson>
```

I am calling the individual attribute value in my code as follows:

```
attrVal_New = Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value;
string attributelowercase = attrVal_New.ToLower();

m++;
```

what i want is to use 'STATE' and 'STATUS' available under `TestCondition` one by one.Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried googling for ["How to split a string in C#"](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+split+a+string+in+c%23)? The "XML attribute" part is completely unrelated to your problem, especially since you've already solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your real xml is valid

```
string[] vals = XDocument.Load(fName)
                    .Root
                    .Element("Bugs")
                    .Attribute("TestCondition")
                    .Value.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a foreach loop and the string.Split method like so:

```
XElement bugsElement = XDocument.Load(fName)
                .Root
                .Element("DrWatson");
List<string> vals = new List<string>();
foreach (XElement el in bugsElement)
{
    vals.AddRange(bugsElement.Attribute("TestCondition").Value.Split(','));
}
```

The string.Split()-method splits your string into an array at the char passed as argument, so

```
"STATE,STATUS,HELP,WHATEVER".Split(',')
```

returns

```
new string[] {"STATE","STATUS","HELP","WHATEVER"};
```

Comment: Actually i have other attributes in the xml available under TestCondition and want to read all in once so that i can iterate them further in my code with a for loop.